# height: 100% on <body> not working in android web app?

Tags: android, html, css, height, viewport

I am developing a web app, and it works great in the browser and when saving it to home screen, on both android and ios. However, when downloading it as an actual app the % height on body doesn't work on android (it works if i set it to a pixel value). I also have some elements that use viewport height, which also doesn't work, which is weird because there is pretty good support for viewport units. It is like the viewport has no height.

Its pretty basic stuff:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="some-element"></div>
    <div class="some-element"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body, html { height: 100%; }
.container { height: 100%; }
.some-element { height: 50vh; }
```

Can it have anything to do with the "shell" (which I haven't been involved in doing) that is used when it is installed as an app?

Answer (score 0):

`vh` units have very poor support on android devices, so unless you are using android 4.4+ you are -unfortunately- out of luck.

You can check `vh` unis support at http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

To be honest although `vh` and `vw` units are great, I still avoid using them since there has been so poor support from android.

As a solution to your problem, try using a `div` styled as a table and use `height:50%` to get the same result. If you need any additional support, update your relative code and I (or someone else) will help you out.